# Proper Incrementing while using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a bit new to the Google scripting scene. I've gone over this so many times and I can't wrap my brain around incrementing properly.

I've created a Google Spreadsheet that uses a form. When someone uses the form to submit equipment, it's going to use a Send Email function (MailApp.sendEmail) to e-mail it to the accounting people.

So far, I can populate the spreadhsheet perfectly, but when the function runs, it only labels the 'status' variable in the 1st row and doesn't continue through the list, then it e-mails that 1 row several times. Can anyone see where I'm going so wrong on this?

I need this to submit the data to the next row that available, then the script checks the last cell for EMAIL_SENT and if it doesn't have that value, I need it to send an e-mail and then check the next row of data as well (in case I need to manually run the script from within the spreadsheet). I couldn't find a similar question on here where I could understand what I'm doing wrong with the incrementing and looping.

Here's the script:

```
function sendThisOut() {
  // set the current spreadsheet and active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // set range data
  var sRow = 2;  // first top left cell of data
  var cols = 9; // Num of cols 

  // define initial data source and get values
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sRow,1,1,cols);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // increment data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

    // define each column
    var tstamp = row[0]; // get timestamp (col A)
    var acct = row[1]; // define account (col B)
    var cname = row[2]; // define client name (col C)
    var comment = row[3]; // define comments (col D)
    var item1 = row[4]; // defines item 1 (col E)
    var item2 = row[5]; // defines item 2 (col F)
    var item3 = row[6]; // defines item 3 (col G)
    var item4 = row[7]; // defines item 4 (col H)
    var status = row[8]; // get status (emailed or no?)

    // setup e-mail vars
    var emailAddr = "myEmail@myDomain.com";
    var subject = "ACCT:" + acct + " " + cname + " - Equipment Request";

    // setup content of e-mail
    var body = "Hello Accounting,\n\n" +
        "Please bill for the contained items on the following account:\n\n" +
        "Account: " + acct + "\n\n" +
        "Client Name: " + cname + "\n\n" +
        "Item 1: " + item1 + "\n\n" +
        "Item 2: " + item2 + "\n\n" +
        "Item 3: " + item3 + "\n\n" +
        "Item 4: " + item4 + "\n\n" +
        "Reason for rekey: " + comment;

    // check status and if it doesn't have EMAIL_SENT, email it
    if (status != "EMAIL_SENT") {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddr, subject, body);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      sheet.getRange(sRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    };

  };
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If I didn't quite ask properly, I apologize. I'm just trying to figure this stuff out and this little knook is kicking my butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned above, I had to keep going over and over this. Finally, through learning a different technique and finding a few spread out threads, I ended up with the following script that:
- simply checks the last row of data at time of submission
- Has the user submit a form
- Emails intended parties
- Updates spreadsheet
- Watches for breaks
- Provides confirmation of email / breaks

I hope this helps someone else out there. So far I'm still working on a script that will scan out the entire spreadsheet, but this script checks the last row on submission of a form, which answers my particular question. I'll try to post the answer when I find my answer to the full sheet scan:

**(PS: Might be smoother to past this into Google Scripter. I've added a lot of comments to keep myself and anyone reading this on track of what's going on)**

```
function other() {
  // set the current sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // set the last row and column
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lcol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // set the major row range and data values
  var rowRng = sheet.getRange(lrow, 1, 1, lcol);
  var rowData = rowRng.getValues()[0];

  // setup redundancy checks for status and email
  // data status, email status and submitter are added to column headers AFTER form creation
  var statrng = sheet.getRange(lrow, 8); // set range of status
  var stat = statrng.getValue(); // get value of status in col h
  var emsrng = sheet.getRange(lrow, 9); // set range of emailed status
  var ems = emsrng.getValue(); // get value of emailed status in col i

  // get current submitters data and set ranges for it, then apply data to sheet
  var suberng = sheet.getRange(lrow, 10); // set range of submitters email
  var sube = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); // get submitters email
  suberng.setValue(sube); // set subs email to sheet in col j

  // setup the per cell data
  var tstamp = rowData[0]; // col a: set timestamp (created when forms created)
  var cname = rowData[1]; // col b: set the client name
  var acct = rowData[2]; // col c: set the account number cell
  var it1 = rowData[3]; // col d: set item 1
  var it2 = rowData[4]; // col e: set item 2
  var it3 = rowData[5]; // col f: set item 3
  var it4 = rowData[6]; // col g: set item 4

  // setup email vars
  var em = "myEmail@myDomain.com"; // email that data needs to go too
  var sub = "ACCT: " +acct+ " - " +cname+ "Request"; // subject in email
  var body = "Hello Accounting,\n\n"
      + "Please order the following:\n\n"
      + "Item 1: " +it1
      + "\nItem 2: " +it2
      + "\nItem 3: " +it3
      + "\nItem 4: " +it4
      + "\n\nPlease send us the invoicing once complete."
      + "\n\nSubmitted by\n"
      + sube + " : " + tstamp;

  // Now that all variables have been set, run checks and send the email as well
  // as a confirmation email. If script doesn't complete, a failure notice is sent if possible

  // as long as there's a timestamp and submitted status is empty, run if statement
  if (tstamp !== "" && stat == "") {
    statrng.setValue("Submitted"); // update status field since we've gotten this far
    var statu = statrng.getValue(); // make sure update took for status
    if (statu == "Submitted") {
      if (ems == "") { // no need to continue if email has already been sent, so check
        MailApp.sendEmail(em, sub, body); // send to accounting people
        emsrng.setValue("Emailed"); // update status that email was successfully sent
        // let submitter know it was a success
        MailApp.sendEmail(sube,"ACCT: " +acct+ " - Submission Successful","Your Submission was Successful!");
      }
    } else {
      // if form failed, let submitter know it was not a success
      MailApp.sendEmail(sube,"ACCT: " +acct+ " - Submission Successful","Your Submission was Successful!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: REMINDER: Need to keep a couple of things in mind about this script.
* When creating the form, don't add 'Submitted', 'Emailed' and 'Subs Email:' columns to the form. These should be added after the form is created so it doesn't prompt the submitter for that info.

* Also, while the script editor is open, go to resources and setup the trigger so that it's:
**yourScript->fromSpreadsheet->OnSubmit** or it will not run it unless you label the function onSubmit (I think)

Comment: WARNING: It seems that the class/method of getActiveUser() doesn't work for non-business version of gmail. I tried running the form from another gmail account and it just keeps adding the original users info. I do know that this works in the business version of gmail though, but if you're not paying for that, I'd recommend adding another value to the form for the user to enter their email and/or name atleast for accountability **In reference to this: [var sube = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();]**

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at

```
 sheet.getRange(sRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

Shouldn't this be (observe the double quotes)

```
  sheet.getRange(sRow + i, 9).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
```

Comment: You're right. The reason I ended up with that is because at one point I have var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

> it only labels the 'status' variable in the 1st row and doesn't continue through the list,

The reason you are only affecting the first row is the third argument in:

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sRow,1,***1***,cols);

which should specify the number of rows in your data set and as you can see it is 1(one) which results in only one row in dataRange. Try the following and see if it helps:

```
// set range data
  var sRow = 2;  // first top left cell of data
  var cols = 9; // Num of cols 
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow() - sRow + 1
  // define initial data source and get values
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sRow,1,rows,cols);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
```

---

> then it e-mails that 1 row several times.

Not sure about this unless during your testing you may have set multiple triggers? Try it after the above change and post back if still having problems.

Comment: I tried that and got the following error:
"The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid."

I ended up rewriting this so many times and looking all over the place, I found a solution. Going to post it below. Thanks for the suggestion.