# ABOUT: Tutorial: Sending emails from a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to get this script updated? In 2009 it may have worked, but it doesn't now.

Tutorial: Sending emails from a Spreadsheet -
[Quick link to Google Developers Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)

I can't for the life of me get my own script to work. Having a problem incrementing the rows correctly when it checks before sending, which is either leaving me sending a dozen e-mails of a single row of data or if I try to implement a while loop, I've ended up sending myself over hundreds of e-mails and google then stops me from using the function any further until the next day.

My specific script question is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769935/proper-incrementing-while-using-mailapp-sendemail), except I don't think I worded it correctly because no one is replying.

Comment: The reason no one replied to your other post is because you had it tagged wrong. I changed the tag to google-apps-script and gave an answer there.

Comment: Hi Michael, glad to see we gave exactly the same answer ;-) but your right : it had to be answered on the original post... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot a couple of things in your script :

1° :  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sRow,1,1,cols); // this gets only 1 row in your sheet so it is normal that the loop doesn't work (length=1).
I'd suggest to replace the height value by the last row value (see [docs to get that value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getLastRow)) to make the loop iterate through every rows.

2° when you use .setValue(EMAIL_SENT); the value of EMAIL_SENT is not defined in your code (it is defined outside the function in the tutorial).
I'd suggest to add a statement like this : var EMAIL_SENT="EMAIL_SENT" or, more simply use the string value in your 'setValue' statement like this : .setValue("EMAIL_SENT");

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've answered both of these in the original script as well. This post is more to ask if someone can update that script (crossing fingers). In any case, I was able to create a successful script targeting the last row on submission. Thanks a lot for your help (and the update to tag - I'm new to this type of site setup).